# Is it possible to fail a build if i try to use the same snapshot version?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

Is it possible to fail a build if i try to use the same snapshot version.. Currently i have created ci/cd pipeline through Jenkins file and my requirement is, if there is already an existing snapshot version and if we are trying to build one more for the same snapshot version, then the build should fail. For example: if i have my 4.12, and if i try to create one more build for the same snapshot version it should fail. I am aware currently maven overwrites them for each build iteration. Just trying to understand if we could fail.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find a way, but you should not do it.

If a version is "final" and should not be overwritten, use a release version. If you want to be able to overwrite a version, use snapshot. I see no reason why one would create a snapshot version and the forbid to overwrite it.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my post clearly. My intention is not to overwrite any, i said maven currently overwrites the existing version if we haven't changed the snapshot version which i am aware . I was curious to know if i could fail a build, if i use the same snapshot version again

Comment: @user11881 I said: If you want a build to fail if you use the version again, just don't use a snapshot version. Snapshot versions are meant to be used several times.

Comment: you seemed to misunderstand the concept of a `SNAPSHOT` version. A SNAPSHOT version is defined as `being under development` which means for a version `1.0-SNAPSHOT` you are working towards the final release version `1.0` but yet not reached it. So it will change over the time.

Comment: @JFMeier, - thanks for the clarity .. i will try to implement my sceanrio and keep you guys posted

Comment: @user11881 If you would describe the original problem you are trying to solve (which is probably not the one you described in the question), we might be more able to help you.

Comment: @JFMeier thank you. My scope is to fail a build if i use the same version again in my pom.xml. not sure if its a release or snapshot version. sorry i am just totally new to these stuff .. however after your suggestion i understood that a snapshot version means to use several times and release version can have only unique number.(if am right)

Comment: @JFMeier i tried using the same version number for final version, however maven doesn't fail them. is this a valid one. please assist

Comment: `mvn deploy` should fail if the artifact is already present in your Nexus/Artifactory. You can, however, change the default behaviour of Nexus to allow overwrites.